# TypeScript function inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, typescript, angular

I don't even know if this is possible in TypeScript, but I'm trying to inherit a function from a Class, like this:

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({})
class Class1 {
  name: string;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  private setName() {
    this.name = "test";
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.setName();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'test'
})
export class Class2 extends Class1 {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    super.ngAfterViewInit();
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

but I'm getting the following error in console when calling the setName() function:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.el is undefined

Why isn't this working?

Comment: The setName() function actually is: `this.name = this.el.nativeElement.firstChild;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited. You need to define them in each subclass

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test'
})
export class Class2 extends Class1 {
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    super(el);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    super.ngAfterViewInit();
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Constructors are not inherited.

They are. Following sample shows this:

```
class Parent {  
    constructor(foo:number){}
}
class Child extends Parent {    
}

const child1 = new Child(); // Error!
const child2 = new Child(123); // OKAY!
```

## But this is angular

However they are not analyzed for dependency injection. This means that your child class constructor isn't called with the same parameters as expected by the parent (in your case `el). You need to specify all the *DI* elements on each child class. So *by chance* the correct code is the one from the accepted answer:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test'
})
export class Class2 extends Class1 {
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    super(el);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider updating `el`'s scope to `protected`, meaning it can be accessed by both the class where it's declared and any derived classes.

```
// before
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

// after
constructor(protected el: ElementRef) {}
```